# JavaScript and Unicode

Tags: javascript, unicode

I want to convert my english alphabets to arabic using JavaScript

Do I need to do some kind Unicode conversion for this? An example would be great.

Comment: Can you be more clear about what you mean by converting English to Arabic ("Sun" -> "الشمس")? Or some sort of alphabetic substitution ("s" -> "س")? Or perhaps something phonetic?

Answer (score 0):

Well first make sure the file you are saving is Unicode UTF-8, otherwise the characters get all messed up.
Do you mean conversion from english to arabic?

If you are converting letter for letter I would recommend making a function will all arabic unicode characters and english letters.

ie.

```
function en_to_ar(string) {
    var convert = new Array();
    convert["a"] = "/u...";
    ... divide string into every letter, loop through, output result
}
```

But watch out, Arabic is tricky. With all the vowel marks and stuff. Remember vowel marks count as another character. Also unicode is multi-byte, so .length on an arabic letter vs an english ascii letter will not be the same.

http://javascript.about.com/library/blunicode.htm